# Google AuthenticatorFactory replacement?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

The 'First App' tutorial for Google Calendar API uses AuthenticatorFactory when authenticating the application with Google.  According to [this link](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/detail?r=1569975f1615a5a2a01eaf9153ad21997c0c05b1&path=/Src/GoogleApis.Tools.CodeGen/Decorator/ServiceDecorator/StandardConstructServiceDecorator.cs), AuthenticatorFactory was removed from the API on Aug 8, 2011.  Can anyone point me in the direction to find the 'new' way to authenticate my application with Google?

EDIT:  Just realized that I didn't include the language I'm using - I'm looking for examples on how to authenticate/authorize an installed C# application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for opening an old topic, but I came accross the same question and it took me quite some time to find the solution. So for all the people with the same problem:

AuthenticatorFactory won't work, you need to create your service like with the following code:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthentication);

// Create the service.
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
     Authenticator = auth
});
```

Good luck!